# How to add additional menu item in right click in CkEditor?

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

In CKeditor, when we right click on image, there are four menu items that appear.

```
cut
copy
paste
image properties
```

I would like to add two more menu items,

```
test1
test2 -> subtest2
         subtest3
```

test1 will be one menu and test2 will have two sub menus.

Also, how can I add action to this new menu item? For example, click on test1 should draw a border on right side. clicking on subtest2 will add image shadow and so on.

In addition to this. I would like to do similar when we right-click on div and table.

I have found context menu plugins but I need to know how can I use this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I met this problem, too. Thanks to the bad documentation of CKEditor, I finally make it by trying different ways the whole afternoon.
This code works well on my site -- Drupal 6 & CKEditor 4.

```
// Assume I already Have 3 commands
// insertTick, insertTickxxx, and insertTickxxxandxxx

if (editor.addMenuItems) {
  // 1st, add a Menu Group
  // tip: name it the same as your plugin. (I'm not sure about this)
  editor.addMenuGroup('tick', 3);

  // 2nd, use addMenuItems to add items
  editor.addMenuItems({
      // 2.1 add the group again, and give it getItems, return all the child items
      tick :
      {
        label : 'Insert Tick',
        group : 'tick',
        order : 21,
        getItems : function() {
          return {
            tick_insertTick : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
            tick_insertQuestionMark : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
            tick_insertTickandQuestion : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF
          };
        }
      },

      // 2.2 Now add the child items to the group.
      tick_insertTick :
      {
        label : 'Insert a tick',
        group : 'tick',
        command : 'insertTick',
        order : 22
      },

      tick_insertQuestionMark :
      {
        label : 'Insert Question Mark',
        group : 'tick',
        command : 'insertQuestionMark',
        order : 23
      },

      tick_insertTickandQuestion :
      {
        label : 'insert Tick and Question',
        group : 'tick',
        command : 'insertTickandQuestion',
        order : 24
      }
  });
}

// 3rd, add Listener, and return the Menu Group
if (editor.contextMenu) {
  editor.contextMenu.addListener(function(element, selection) {
    return {
      tick : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF
    };
  });
}
```

and this will show like

Insert Tick -> Insert a tick

-------------- Insert a Question Mark

-------------- Insert a tick and question mark

Comment: You're right, CKEditor has terrible documentation!!  Thanks for doing the work for us!  This works brilliantly for my custom widget.

Comment: I found this code needs to be in the plugin `init` function in my plugin definition, for those wondering.

Comment: I used this to remove the other items (insert just before: `if (editor.addMenuItems) {` :

`editor.removeMenuItem('cut'); editor.removeMenuItem('copy'); editor.removeMenuItem('paste');`

Comment: @SeanKendle that works for removing the the menus. Mysteriously your last removeMenuItem command has a "&zwnj;" character after the capital 'I' and before the following 't'! It's invisible, but it's there.

Comment: Strange.  Well, thanks for pointing that out for others that might run into issues copy/pasting that code!  It seems it's a zero-width non-joiner, which shows as a "pipe" character in IE.  It's probably inserted by StackOverflow to allow a word to break to the next line, since that's not default HTML behavior.

Comment: The answer will only work if you register 'insertQuestionMark', 'insertTickandQuestion' and 'insertTick' commands using editor.addCommand.

Answer (score 1):

1. Register a new ckEditor command;
2. Add a new menu group;
3. Add new menu item;
4. Add click event listener to the context menu.

   ```
       // Register a command execute on context menu item click
       editor.addCommand('test1', {
           exec: editor => {
               console.log(editor);
               alert('test1');
           }
       });

       // Check for context menu and add new item/s
       if ( editor.contextMenu ) {
           // Add group and item/s
           editor.addMenuGroup( 'testGroup' );
           editor.addMenuItem( 'testItem', {
               label: 'Test 1',
               icon: this.path + 'icons/test.png',
               command: 'test1',
               group: 'testGroup'
           });

           // Add event listener
           editor.contextMenu.addListener(element => {
               console.log(element);
               return { testItem: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF };
           });
       }
   ```

For more information check this link:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_2.html

Answer (score 0):

I am also try the same.Finally i got one solution.so here i share it.it may help others.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
   // Menu code
 var config = {
  toolbar: [],
removePlugins : 'pastetext,clipboard'   
 };

var editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo('ckeditor', config);



editor.on( 'instanceReady', function(e) { 
 var e = e.editor;

  // Commands
e.addCommand("cv_claimant_Birthdate", {
    exec: function(e) {
        e.insertText("\{\!claimant.Birthdate\}");
    }
});
e.addCommand("cv_claimant_Name", {
    exec: function(e) {
        e.insertText("\{\!claimant.Name\}");
    }
});
e.addCommand("cv_claim_Name", {
    exec: function(e) {
        e.insertText("\{\!claim.Name\}");
    }
});
e.addCommand("cv_claim_CreatedDate", {
    exec: function(e) {
        e.insertText("\{\!claim.CreatedDate\}");
    }
});

// Listener
e.contextMenu.addListener(function(element, selection) {
    return {
        cv: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON
    };
});

// Menu Groups; different numbers needed for the group separator to show
e.addMenuGroup("cv", 500);
e.addMenuGroup("cv_people", 100);
e.addMenuGroup("cv_claim", 200);

// Menus (nested)
e.addMenuItems({
    // Top level
    cv: {
        label: "Insert Merge Field",
        group: "cv",
        getItems: function() {
            return {
                cv_claimant: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
                cv_claim: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
            };
        }
    },
    // One sub-menu
    cv_claimant: {
        label: "Claimant Person (claimant)",
        group: "cv_people",
        getItems: function() {
            return {
                cv_claimant_Birthdate: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
                cv_claimant_Name: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
            };
        }
    },
    // These run commands
    cv_claimant_Birthdate: {
        label: "Birthdate (Birthdate: date)",
        group: "cv_people",
        command: "cv_claimant_Birthdate"
    },
    cv_claimant_Name: {
        label: "Full Name (Name: string)",
        group: "cv_people",
        command: "cv_claimant_Name"
    },
    // Another sub-menu
    cv_claim: {
        label: "Claim (claim)",
        group: "cv_claim",
        getItems: function() {
            return {
                cv_claim_CreatedDate: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
                cv_claim_Name: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
            };
        }
    },
    // These run commands
    cv_claim_Name: {
        label: "Claim Number (Name: string)",
        group: "cv_claim",
        command: "cv_claim_Name"
    },
    cv_claim_CreatedDate: {
        label: "Created Date (CreatedDate: datetime)",
        group: "cv_claim",
        command: "cv_claim_CreatedDate"
    },
});
 });   






</script>
```