# How to add a new property in cell property in CKEditor Table

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to add a text rotation property in table cell of CKEditor.Is there any way to add a new cell property in CKEditor table.I want to rotate my cell text vertically.

Answer (score 0):

hi you should use external plugin,
1.add your name plugin in ckeditor.js
2.build a tree folder similar http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1 & continu..
3.add button
4.add your js & css rotate code in function addEventOnkey(editor) {}
5.injoy

Comment: thanx for reply ,this will add property in toolbar,I need to add it into in table's right click this link helped me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506884/ckeditor-how-to-add-additional-menu-item-in-right-click?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: but my main question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104275/how-to-enable-vertical-text-in-table-in-ckeditor        do you have any solution for this thanks:)